# Custom filter backend or Django-Filter?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I work on simple Django project that uses DRf and I have small problem. I want to add filtering and searching to my API endpoints, but I don't know which way is better:

1. Make custom filter backend for filtering and searching logic.
2. Use Django-Filter package for this task.

Here is part of my code now:

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters

class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['title', 'description']
```

I am just wondering, which method is better for performance, easy to maintain, and follows best practices?
Can you tell me pros and cons for both methods and any problems I can have? For example, if I make custom filter backend, how to make it good? If I choose Django-Filter, are there problems or limits I should know?

I am very thankful for any help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your situation. Most of the time I would go with a maintained packege. This way if there are bugs or updates, the package will be updated when needed to.  When you need highly specific filtering, most of the time writing your own is better.

For performence, most of the time you should work with what is easy and fast to implement. When your application grows, you will automaticly see what parts are to slow, and you can fix these part specificly. This way you keep momentum in your project. Golden rule is that speed of development and maintainablitiy should have priority over performence. Only when performence becomes an issue, you should update that part.